# Compare the difference of image dehaze algorithm between FotoJet and Polarr

Tags: image, algorithm

I'm developing a image editor by webgl. I did some research with the existing apps which contains image dehaze effect, [FotoJet](https://www.fotojet.com/) and [Polarr](https://photoeditor.polarr.co/). Here are the example images exported by FotoJet and Polarr.

Original:

[image]

FotoJet:

[image]

Polarr:

[image]

So, what's the dehaze algorithm they used? I think their algorithm is different, can anyone help me figure out the algorithms?

Comment: I am not sure if this is the right place, to ask this question.

Comment: Okay, is this illegal? Maybe I just want to know how to implement the image dehaze effect.

Comment: Its not illegal, it just doesn't suite stackoverflow very well, to me it looks like some sharpening and HSL adjustment based on a saturation low-pass / threshold.

Comment: So, anybody has the reference of the algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

I find the algorithm of Kaiming He at http://kaiminghe.com/cvpr09/. I think it's the solution.

The FotoJet and Polarr don't implement the perfect result as Kaiming He's Demo. I'll try it by myself.